# JavaScript Date Masking issue

Tags: javascript, html

I made a pretty good date mask with the help of StackOverflow. Seems to be working mostly since I am using date function instead of hacky splits slice. But i have a bug may need some slicing and replacing. So below code is essentially formatting all dates to month/day/year(00/00/0000) format. typical 1-2-91,01-1-1991 etc are all formatting correctly, except when I use no separators and input the date like '01011991'(want 01/01/1991), its giving back invalid date/nan. I am thinking of all scenarios, this sequence should work since only thing missing is the slash. it's even formatting to 01/01/2001 when i only put '1' in the field

```js
function execute () {
  var new_date = document.getElementById('date_val').value;
  var j = format(new_date);
  document.getElementById('date_val').value = j; 
}

function format(incoming_date) {
  
  var d = new Date(incoming_date);
  console.log('new date', d)
  day = d.getDate();
  month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  year = d.getFullYear();
  return (String(month).length == 1 ? '0' + month : month) + '/' + (String(day).length == 1 ? '0' + day : day) + '/' + year;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
date: <input type="text" id="date_val" onblur="execute()"> 
  
  <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="./js/test.js"></script> -->
  <script src="./js/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What your code do is just using `Date` constructor to parse a string to a date object which is equivalent to [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). Please refer to the documentation on all formats that recognized by `Date.parse()`. Extra effort needed if the format is not a standard format as specified.

Answer (score 0):

so basically made a onkey function that checks and add '/' for the first two of date (day and month)

```js
function execute () {
  var new_date = document.getElementById('date_val').value;
  var a   = new_date.replace(/\//gi, "-");
  
  var j = format(a);
  document.getElementById('date_val').value = j; 
}

function format(incoming_date) {
  console.log("check entered",incoming_date)
  var d = new Date(incoming_date);
  console.log('new date', d)
  day = d.getDate();
  console.log('check day',day);

  month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  console.log('check month',month);
  year = d.getFullYear();
  console.log('check year',year);

  return (String(month).length == 1 ? '0' + month : month) + '/' + (String(day).length == 1 ? '0' + day : day) + '/' + year;
};

function onkey(){

var e = document.getElementById('date_val');
 
        var numChars = e.value.length;
        if(numChars === 2 || numChars === 5){
            var thisVal = e.value;
            thisVal += '/';
            e.value = thisVal;
        }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="date_val"  onkeyup="onkey()"> 
  
  <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="./js/test.js"></script> -->
  <script src="./js/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```